# Webextension to log in to certain page and continue with subpage by one click

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, popup, firefox-addon-webextensions

im dealing with combination of popup, content script and background script. Unfotrunatelly any communication I chose among them failed to me to get desired result.

I need to develop webextension with icon/popup in browser menu. Once it is clicked, it opens dedicated menu with items in popup window.
When i click on popup certain item.. tab should be opened and it should go to certain URL to log in (via URL with parameters or POST) and go to subpage (specific to popup item text).

I was trying many combinations of messagings between popup & bg script, between bg script & content script etc. ... but it never worked to me. I had also problems with synchronizations of requests, because although i logged in (via windows.open) i could perform further subpage to load.

Do you have guys idea how this could work? the best with some shor example?
I used only standard javascript.

My FIRST attempt:

**manifest.json**

```
{
  "description": "test",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "extensiontest",
  "version": "1.0",
  "homepage_url": "https://xxxx.com",
  "icons": {
    "32": "beasts-32.png"
  },


  "applications": {
    "gecko": {
      "id": "testid@sss.com",
      "strict_min_version": "45.0"
    }
  },

  "content_scripts": 
  [
    {
      "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
      "run_at": "document_end",
      "js": ["content.js"]
    }
  ],

"browser_action": 
  {
  "default_icon": "popup.png",
  "default_popup":"popup.html"
  },

"background": 
  {
  "scripts": ["background.js"]
  },

"permissions": 
  [
    "tabs","storage"
  ]
}
```

**popup.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="links.css"/>
</head>
<script src="popup.js"></script>
<body>
    <ul>
    <li><a id="bQuote" href="#">Quote</a></li>
    <li><a id="bSend" href="#">Send</a></li>
    </ul>
</body></html>
```

**popup.js**

```
function goQuote() {

    chrome.tabs.query({currentWindow: true, active: true}, function (tabs){
    var activeTab = tabs[0];
    chrome.tabs.sendMessage(activeTab.id, {"message": "Quote"});
   });

  // Generic Log In link
  window.open("Login-link","targetname");

}

function goSend() {

    chrome.tabs.query({currentWindow: true, active: true}, function (tabs){
    var activeTab = tabs[0];
    chrome.tabs.sendMessage(activeTab.id, {"message": "Send"});
   });

  // Generic Log In link
  window.open("Login-link","targetname");

}


document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  document.getElementById("bQuote").addEventListener("click", goQuote);
  document.getElementById("bSend").addEventListener("click", goSend);
});
```

**content.js**

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
      function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
        if( request.message === "Quote" ) {

          // Subpage link with same target name
          window.open("supbpage-link1","targetname");
             }
        if( request.message === "Send" ) {
          // Subpage link with same target name
          window.open("supbpage-link2","targetname");
             }
      }
    );
```

Comment: It would help if you describe your attempts in more detail, highlighting what didn't work.

Comment: i cannot get into specific subpage, based on clicked popup item.. i always get into first page after log in....

Comment: Im looking for the concept.. what is the way and what files be used to click poup item, open tab, logo in, then go further to certain subpage

Comment: It seems like you already _have_ a concept yourself. If you show relevant parts of your best attempt, it would be easier to point out what went wrong and suggest how to fix it. It also frees us from guessing just how much you understand already. Writing a whole "short sample" isn't really short and would be too broad by Stack Overflow standards.

Comment: @Xan... ok i update the original question wuith first attempt I did... all of them have same result of not getting into subpage.. therefore not sure which one is the closests to the soultion...

Comment: So, what you want is as follows: open the **login-page**, and AFTER it transitions to **logged-in-page**, redirect the tab to destination dependent of the choice? Am I understanding it correctly?

Comment: @Xan, open login-page URL which redirects to sitemap and AFTER go to certain subpage based on initial choice/item from popup menu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a background script to orchestrate things.

In `popup.js` use `chrome.runtime.sendMessage()` to send message to a `background.js` on click event.

In `background.js`:

1. `chrome.runtime.onMessage()` to catch a message from `popup.js`
2. `chrome.tabs.create()` to open login page and remember tab id;
3. `chrome.webNavigation.onCompleted.addEventListener()` to detect tab is loaded (you need an event with `tabId` that you remembered and `frameId === 0`);
4. `chrome.tabs.executeScript()` on that tab to inject `content.js` that will fill form and submit it;
5. `chrome.webNavigation.onCompleted.addEventListener()` again to detect tab is loaded;
6. `chrome.tabs.update()` to navigate to desired subpage;
7. cleanup.

And keep in mind that anytime anything can go wrong: user may interrupt page loading, credentials may be wrong, network connection may disappear, etc. :)

Comment: That seems to be promising!. Will take some time to create it to know final result. Many thanks!